# Generalization of classic 3 roll die game to $n$ rolls

Tags: probability, probability-theory, puzzle, dice

I am trying to generalize the following well-known 3 roll die problem:

"We roll a single die no more than 3 times. We can stop immediately after the first roll, immediately after the second roll, or we can wait for the third. The gain is the same number of dollars as there are dots on the single upturned face of the last roll. What is the expected value of this game?"

Proceeding by backward reasoning, we can easily show that the expected value $E_3$ of the 3 roll problem is equal to $14/3$. This is my attempt to find the expected value $E_n$ of the $n$ roll problem. Let $n_0$ be the number of rolls such that $E_{n_0}$ reaches $5$ for the first time (in actuality, it turns out that $n_0=5$ because we easily find $E_4=4.94$ and $E_5=5.13$). For all $n>n_0$, we then have the relation:

$$E_n=\frac{5}{6}\times E_{n-1}+\frac{1}{6}\times 6=\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n-n_0}\left(E_{n_0}-6\right)+6,$$

as we proceed to the $n$-th roll if we get $1,2,3,4$ or $5$ on roll $n-1$ and stop if we get $6$. As $n$ approaches infinity, we also see that:

$$E:=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E_n=6.$$

Finally, as a sanity check, given that $E_{n_0}-6<0$, we have $E_n<6$ for all $n\geq n_0$.

I guess I don't really have a specific question, but just wondering if the general reasoning and arguments behind this generalization seemed correct? Any comments or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't your recursion read "$\frac 16\times 6$"?

Comment: @lulu thanks, corrected

Comment: Other than that, the approach looks solid. As a general rule, it's hard to value ongoing (i.e. "American") options but in this case, as you point out, it's pretty clear when you should stop.

Comment: @lulu ok cool, yes in this case the optimal stopping rule is clear. I think the only small thing to watch out for is that the recursion is only defined once we have reached 5.